# single-element enum type singletone with lazy loading capability

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, jvm, singleton

I read many forums and posts about different style to implement single-tone pattern in java and seems "Enum are the best way to implement singletone pattern in java"!!
I wonder how can i use Java Enum to implement SingleTone pattern in java **with lazy-loading** capability. since Enums are just classes. The first time a class is used, it gets loaded by the JVM and all of its static initialization is done. the enum members are static , so they're all going to be initialized.

**does anyone know how can i use enum with lazyloading support?**

Comment: Something that your little quote about lazy-loading doesn't mention is that the JVM does the lazy-loading in a _thread-safe_ manner. This is why using this kind of lazy class loading is the preferred method—the JVM handles all the synchronization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Lazy Initializing Singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842273/java-lazy-initializing-singleton)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the source you read said it's the easiest way to do lazy singletons is because it should just work. Try this:

```
public class LazyEnumTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Sleeping for 5 seconds...");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Accessing enum...");
    LazySingleton lazy = LazySingleton.INSTANCE;
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }
}

enum LazySingleton {
  INSTANCE;
  static { System.out.println("Static Initializer"); }
}
```

Here's the output I get in the console:

```
$ java LazyEnumTest
Sleeping for 5 seconds...
Accessing enum...
Static Initializer
Done.
```

Answer (score 8):

> The first time a class is used, it gets loaded by the JVM and all of its static initialization is done. the enum members are static , so they're all going to be initialized.

Actually, classloader loads classes (sounds funny) only after you are accessing this classes first time. And only one reason to access *enum-singleton* class is to get it's instance.

That is why single-element enum type singletone in Java are called **lazy** - it's value is not initialized before you first time access it.

### Similar questions:

- [Java: Lazy Initializing Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842273/java-lazy-initializing-singleton)
- [Lazy-loaded singleton: Double-checked locking vs Initialization on demand holder idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189099/lazy-loaded-singleton-double-checked-locking-vs-initialization-on-demand-holder)

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. Here is some more: [why enum singleton](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.tr/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html?m=1)