# how to prevent invoke private constructor through reflect in Java

Tags: java

I have a java class named `Test` which has a single, private constructor because I require it to be a singleton, like this:

```
class Test {
    private static final Test INSTANCE = new Test();
    private Test() { }
    public static Test getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }

    // other code
}
```

How to prevent others from instantiating `Test` through reflection in Java?

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet for the words ___java singleton prevent reflection___ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can throw exception in private contructor if object is already created,

```
private Test() {
    if (INSTANCE != null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Instance already created");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use enum as they are internally created, initialized by JVM. Invocation of enum is also done internally, so they cannot be accessed by reflection as well

```
public enum Test
{ 
  INSTANCE; 

//other methods etc

}
```

PS: drawback is you won't be able to lazy initialize it. However some threads have suggested that they can be lazy intialized
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15470565/4148175 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771449/4148175